# Scaled-down images are blurry in mobile safari (only on 1 page)

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile-safari, responsive-design

I created [a website](http://tomreinert.de/relaunch/index.php). The images on the [projects page](http://tomreinert.de/relaunch/index.php?p=projekte) appear blurry when viewed in mobile safari. The images on the [project detail page](http://tomreinert.de/relaunch/index.php?p=k) however, are perfectly sharp.

I can't figure out, what's blurring the images. The images' resolution is high enough, so it doesn't have anything to do with the retina display.

Answer (score 0):

You are using html to resize your images. Use photoshop or in code to make a seperate, resampled smaller version of the files.

Browsers resize images poorly, you should use software to resize (can be done in your own code if you like).

Just putting an image size into your markup will make it do a non-resampling resize which often looks rubbish.

This link is dated, but it says what you need to know...
http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/aboutgraphics/l/blresizehtml.htm

The only reason this works on yor pc is that modern pcs will do resampling when they resize in the browser. Not all will do this and mobile ones likely won't.

Comment: Since the website is responsive, i can't set a fixed size. Also the images render perfectly on the subpage. Only on the homepage they are blurred. So it must have something to do with the code.

Comment: @user1792487 By "code", I hope you mean the browser's rendering engine code.

Comment: @user1792487 you are still using safari's rendering engine, and it won't resize images properly.

Comment: I understand. But why do the images on the subpage resize properly? Only on the homepage the images, and even the text is blurred.

Comment: When I remove the link from the image, the image renders sharp. So there is something wrong with the a class.

Comment: Found the solution: The greyscale filter caused the blur. It set webkit-filter to none instead of  grayscale(00%); and now the images are sharp.